# Selenium With TestNG

Tags: selenium, testng, optional-arguments, testng-dataprovider

I am new to selenium with TestNG. It would be great help if you can answer me. I am writing test cases for a webApplication that will create text notes. For testing different kinds of inputs have used @dataProvider. Since I have two options after entering all values i.e either I can save or I can cancel the notes creation. I have used @optional annotation which is throwing an exception. Can you please explain me whether we can use @dataprovider with @optional annotation. I have written code like this.

```
@Test
public class CreateNotesTest extends BeginAndEndTest
{

@Test(dataProvider = "createNotes", dataProviderClass = CreateNotesTest.class)
public void createsNotes(String title,String content,String tags,@Optional("save") String action)
{
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    CreateNotes notes = new CreateNotes(driver);
    boolean status = notes.createNote(title, content, tags, action);
    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("save") || action.equals(""))
        {
        Assert.assertEquals(status, true);
        }
    else
        Assert.assertEquals(status, false);

}
/**
 * 
 * @return dataProvider
 */
@DataProvider(name = "createNotes")
public static Object[][] getNotesData()
{
    return new Object[][]{{"test1","my family is my first priority","family"},{"","hello","greeting","cancel"}};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't use @Optional with dataprovider but only with @Parameters. 
Also if used with parameters,  `if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("save") || action.equals(""))` would throw a nullpointerexception if action is null.